Creating a grid of n tiles so that the grid is approximately square
I have a variable amount of image tiles of specific dimensions that need to be fit into a grid. What is the best method of creating a grid that approximates a square the best?
For example, if the tiles were 1x2, and I had 2 tiles, then it would need to place the 2 tiles next to each other horizontally to create a square image. However, if I had 3 tiles, then it would place 2 across and 1 on the next row, to create the outline of a square grid with 1 tile missing.
This is what I tried, but there's some issues:
tile_number = 12
thumbnail_size = (192, 272) # size of image tiles
ratio_x = thumbnail_size[1]/thumbnail_size[0]
ratio_y = thumbnail_size[0]/thumbnail_size[1]

tr_x, tr_y = tile_number*ratio_x, tile_number*ratio_y
trx_sqrt, try_sqrt = math.sqrt(tr_x), math.sqrt(tr_y)

tile_x, tile_y = round(trx_sqrt), round(try_sqrt)

if tile_x*tile_y < tile_number:
    tile_y += 1
    
print(f'Grid: {tile_x}x{tile_y}')

If I try a grid of 3 tiles, it should give a grid of 2x2, but it gives a grid of 2x1 instead. To fix this, I just manually adjusted the number of rows by 1, if the grid size is lower than the number of images.
Also, for a grid of 9 tiles, it returns a 4x4 grid. I think its calculating that the 4x4 grid of these tiles is more square than the 3x3 grid, but I would rather have the grid be a little less square if it means its filled out better (there will be 3 free spaces in the 4x4, and no free spaces in 3x3 grid).
I thought this was going to be a simple problem, maybe it is and I'm being daft... I cant seem to figure it out though! Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

You're almost there.  Since you want special rules for non-perfect squares (like 3 grids giving 3 x 1, instead of 2 x 2) -- Can try something like this:
def almost_square_grids(ngrids, how='square'):
    nrow = ncol = int(ngrids**0.5) #floor of squareroot
    which = True
    while (nrow * ncol) < ngrids:
        if how == 'square': #flip flop
            which = not which
        elif how == 'extra_rows':
            which = True
        elif how == 'extra_cols':
            which = False

        if which:
            nrow += 1
        else:
            ncol += 1
    return nrow, ncol

print(f"{'N':>3} → {'square':^8}",
      f"{'extra_rows':^12}",
      f"{'extra_cols':^12}", sep='|')
for ngrids in [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16, 17]:
    square = almost_square_grids(ngrids, how='square')
    xrows = almost_square_grids(ngrids, how='extra_rows')
    xcols = almost_square_grids(ngrids, how='extra_cols')
    print(f"{ngrids:>3} → {repr(square):^8}",
          f"{repr(xrows):^12}",
          f"{repr(xcols):^12}", sep='|')

Output:
  N →  square | extra_rows | extra_cols 
  1 →  (1, 1) |   (1, 1)   |   (1, 1)   
  2 →  (1, 2) |   (2, 1)   |   (1, 2)   
  3 →  (2, 2) |   (3, 1)   |   (1, 3)   
  4 →  (2, 2) |   (2, 2)   |   (2, 2)   
  8 →  (3, 3) |   (4, 2)   |   (2, 4)   
  9 →  (3, 3) |   (3, 3)   |   (3, 3)   
 10 →  (3, 4) |   (4, 3)   |   (3, 4)   
 15 →  (4, 4) |   (5, 3)   |   (3, 5)   
 16 →  (4, 4) |   (4, 4)   |   (4, 4)   
 17 →  (4, 5) |   (5, 4)   |   (4, 5)       

Can modify based on thumbnail ratio being more row-like or column-like.

I just realised that I mistakenly put 3x1 instead of 2x2 when creating a 3 tile grid. I have edited it now.
Regarding your code, this assumes that the rows and columns are the same, whereas the tiles wont have the same width and height. Should I multiply the column by the height:width ratio to fix this?
Thank you!
